# What's the right way to apply stylesheet on a class derived from QPushButton?

Tags: qt

i wrote a simple class that derives QPushButton, and tried to apply stylesheet on it.
but it didn't work. 
I read the qt doc, but i could not find the point.
Can any one help me out?

```
class Button : public QPushButton
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
    Button(QWidget * parent = NULL);
    ~Button();
    protected:
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent * event);

};


Button * btn = new Button(rootframe);
// I tried the following ways, all NG.
btn->setStyleSheet("background: white; color: blue;");
btn->setStyleSheet("QPushButton{background: white; color: blue;}");
btn->setStyleSheet("Button {background: white; color: blue;}");
```

Thanks..

Comment: Does it do anything at all? `btn->setStyleSheet("background-color: white; color: blue");` should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `Qt` [Style Sheets Reference](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-reference.html):

> **Warning**: If you only set a background-color on a QPushButton, the
>   background may not appear unless you set the border property to some
>   value. This is because, by default, the QPushButton draws a native
>   border which completely overlaps the background-color.

This should work

```
btn->setStyleSheet("background-color: white; color: blue; border: none");
```

It is advisable to check the [`QPushButton` stylesheets example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qpushbutton).